# AsyncTask return null only on newer Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

could somebody explain why this code works fine with Android 8 and not with 10?

```html
public class SendData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            return Proces.getData(url[0]);
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String text_result){
            super.onPostExecute(text_result);
                    if (text_result != null){
                ;
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Chyba", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }
```

starting task

```html
new SendData().execute(url);
```

Thank you very much for yours answers!

EDIT!

Android 8 return to string text_result html, Android 10 is null

Comment: Do you see any error in your logcat?

Comment: some older one but..
2020-03-24 18:41:05.855 8177-8216/com.example.home E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2020-03-24 18:41:05.855 8177-8216/com.example.home E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da

Comment: do you have a network security config setup? https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

Comment: Does your Asyntask have a constructor?

Comment: I think i dont need security config, i would like to access into my local ip webserver. I tried this, but had no effect.

What you mean with constructor?

Comment: Something is wrong with "return Proces.getData(url[0]);". Because when i wrote some GET argument, nothing happens on web server side (but only with android 10)

Comment: Any idea why thats not working?